# How to disable dock and menubar in fullscreen games with RTS style mouse scrolling?

Tags: dock, menu-bar, fullscreen, games

When playing games that use the newish Mac OS X fullscreen mode (i.e. the icon in the upper right hand corner of the window with two little diagonal arrows), moving the mouse cursor to the top or bottom edge of the screen causes the menubar or the dock to appear, respectively. Aside from being a bad experience, in one game it actually causes a blip in framerate. This is pretty distracting given that scrolling around a map in an RTS or other top-down game is one of the most common user actions.

I've recently run across this issue in two different games (AI War and Invisible Inc) and I'm really hoping that there is some workaround and it's not just the new normal because quite effectively fouls up the experience of playing certain games on OS X.

I wonder if it's possible for the developer to use a different API for fullscreen that makes this a non-issue?